# Not Posting on friend's wall with simple feed method

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have almost wasted my whole day in searching why is it not posting on friends wall

please help

I do not get any errors but the post doesnt seem to be appearing on friends wall.

i get a dialog box saying to post on friends wall.. when i confirm by clicking share it gets closed but no changes on friends wall

I tried on many different friends wall to check for any privacy policy but i dont think thats the matter of concern here.

if i dont specify "to" paramter it gets posted on my profile but only problem is with friends wall

code is as follows

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js">    
</script>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en US/all.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init
    (
        {
            appId  : 'appid',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml  : true , // parse XFBML
            oauth : true // Enable oauth authentication
        }
    );
};

   $(document).ready(function () 
   {
        $('#shareonfacebook').click(function (e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var obj=
            {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'DvimayPostPhoto',
                    link: 'http://localhost/FaceBook/index.html',
                    picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg',
                    caption: 'hey how is my Application ? tell me dude',
                    description: 'hey how is my Application ?',
                    to: 'frnd id',
                    message: ''
            };
            function callback(response)
            {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
            }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);

        });
    }
    );
</script>
<script>
FB.init({appId : 'app id'});
</script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
(function() 
{
     var e = document.createElement('script'); 
     e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     e.sync= true;
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}
);
 </script>

<script src="C:/Users/Dvimay/Desktop/HIGHCHARTS/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="C:/Users/Dvimay/Desktop/HIGHCHARTS/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px;width:500px;"></div>

<input type="button" id="shareonfacebook" value="Share This Link on Facebook"></input>

</html>
```

Comment: pls help me in solving this issue

Comment: I'm assuming you hardcode your friend's Facebook ID in there in place of 'frnd id' ?

Answer (score 0):

What response did you get from FB.ui()? Looking at the code, it seems to be ok. The only possible scenario I could imagine is, your friend has disabled the permission to post on his/her wall. Did you try with any other friend id?

Comment: Definitely try a different Friend ID as Velu suggested. 

Directly from the FB docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/):

'If a person has the "Who can post on your timeline?" setting set to "Only me" and another person tries to make a post using the Feed dialog, it will display a "Cannot post" error.'